# Deploy Apache Solr 5.2.1 on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, solr, war-filedeployment

Just downloaded the latest solr-5.2.1.tgz release from [here](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/mirrors-solr-latest-redir.html). According to [this](https://pacoup.com/2014/02/05/install-solr-4-6-with-tomcat-7-on-debian-7/) and [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/04/install-apache-solr-tomcat/)  post, it should contain the warfile in the `/dist` subdirectory.

But I can't find the warfile in the distribution. Did this change in version  5.x? Where can I get a prebuilt warfile of solr-5.x to deploy on tomcat?

Comment: Just found, that deploying solr as a warfile on tomcat is [no longer supported](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr+on+Tomcat). Does anyone know, whats the reason?

Comment: The reason is that Solr is moving away from the application container model completely, since it's becoming an issue when implementing efficient versions of some of the cloud (cluster) functionality. Official Tomcat support was dropped from 5.x (but probably still works, you just have to do a bit of manual work yourself and you're on your own).

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks for helping me to get the idea behind the discontinuation of tomcat support. Posted my way of going with the latest solr release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since tomcat support seems to be disabled since 5.x I had to dig a bit deeper and finally I found docs [how to start solr](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Installing+Solr) quite easily, even though its not on tomcat.

You just have to unpack the solr-5.2.1.tgz file and then go to `/solr-5.2.1` and do

> $ bin/solr start

which will start the solr server on default port 8983 permanently.

I actually considered deploying the warfile on tomcat the easiest way but that just comes with diverse logging errors you have to handle. So the described way was the one to go for me.